# Echo Dropdown's Option Name Rather Than Its Value

Tags: php, foreach, dropdown, domdocument

I am attempting to `echo` the name of a selected dropdown rather than its value. I understand that `echo`ing a dropdown's value can be achieved by implementing something such as:

```
$variable = $_POST['vehicleStyle'];
echo $variable;
```

where `vehicleStyle` is the `<select>` name.

However, I am not after the `value` I after the  option's name.

Here is my PHP. I am extracting data from a XML Document where `$k` equals the option name and `$v` equals its value.

```
<html>
 <body>

  <?php
    $xml = file_get_contents('note.xml');
    $dom = new DOMDocument();
    $dom->loadXML($xml);
   ?>

    <form action="additionalinfo.php" method=POST>

     <select name="vehicleStyle">
      <option selected="selected">Choose style</option>
      <?php
        foreach ( $dom->getElementsByTagName('style') as $styletwo )   {
          $styleid = $styletwo->getAttribute("name");
          $styleData [$styleid]= $styletwo->getAttribute("id");;
            }
        foreach ($styleData as $k=>$v){
      ?>
    <option value='<?php echo $v;?>'><?php echo $k;?> </option>
     <?php
      }
     ?>
   </select>

   <br>
   <button class="button">Submit</button>
 </form>


 </body>
</html>
```

This outputs a dropdown containing two values: 'Audi=>292015` and 'BMW=>292016'. If I add

```
$variable = $_POST['vehicleStyle'];
echo $variable;
```

to my code, I get either `292015` or `292016` (whichever is selected). How can I echo the dropdown name, either `Audi` or `BMW`?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about...

`<option value='<?php echo $v . '|' . $k;?>'><?php echo $k;?> </option>`

Then

```
$variable = $_POST['vehicleStyle'];
$variable = explode('|', $variable);

echo $variable[0];  //The "value"
echo $variable[1];  //The "text"
```

Might make some validation more difficult but it should get you what you need.

Answer (score 1):

Just change the `value` of the option to `$k` instead i.e.

```
<option value='<?php echo $k;?>'><?php echo $k;?> </option>
```

Comment: I need the value to remain `$v` but I also want to pull the name `$k`

Comment: Today I learned that there are soooooooo many open Stack Overflow pages that demonstrate how to submit both the text and `value` of selected option tags.  I don't even know where to start.

Answer (score 1):

If you only need the text and not the number, then don't include the number as the value in the option.

```
<option><?php echo $k;?></option>
```

[If you don't specify a value attribute, the text will be used as the value by default.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34266445/is-a-select-option-with-no-value-valid/34266512)

If you need to get both the text and the value, there are various suggestions for how to do that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6767748/get-text-from-option-tag-using-php).

Comment: I need the text and the number.