# Combo-box alignment failing in chrome and firefox. The issue seems with style.display = "inline".Looking for a solution

Tags: javascript, html

```js
function RefiPurpose(whichone) {
  if (whichone == "Test 1" || whichone == "") {
    document.getElementById("refi_purp").style.display = "inline";
  } else if (whichone == "Test 2") {
    document.getElementById("refi_purp").style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

```html
<table width="100%" bordercolor="#000033">
  <tr>
    <td style="padding-left:30px">Drop Down 1</td>
    <td style="width:180px"><label name="h_sLoanPurp_err" include="yes"></label>
      <select id="h_sLoanPurp" NAME="h_sLoanPurp" onchange="RefiPurpose(this.value)" include="yes">
        <option>Please Choose One</option>
        <option value="Test 1">Test 1</option>
        <option value="Test 2">Test 2</option>
      </select>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="refi_purp">
    <td style="padding-left:30px" id="refi_purp_td">Drop Down 2:</td>
    <td><label name="h_refipurp_err" include="yes"></label>
      <select id="h_refipurp" NAME="h_refipurp" tabindex="60" include="yes" style="width: 170px"></select>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: First of all is really indicated to use classes (instead of inline styling). 

Second: What is your Test 1 option supposed to do? `style.display = “inline”` is working like is supposed to. The table rows have by default `display: table-row` . By changing that you don't get the normal table-row aspect, instead they are just aligned one after another.

Comment: Its just a sample code snippet. All I want from my code is when we choose test 2 in drop down 1 drop down 2 should be hidden. And if I choose option test 1 drop down 2 should become visible and it should retain its original position.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to get it to the original position you should set the `display` value of the row to `table-row` , because that is the original display value. Also please note your first option has no value. And as you can read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34266445/is-a-select-option-with-no-value-valid/34266512) about this, your first option will have the value `"Please Choose One"` insead of `""`.

Also, as I was saying inline styling is not a good practice. And is better and easier to do it with classes.

So I would recomand something like this:

```js
function RefiPurpose(whichone) {
  if (whichone == "Test 1" || whichone == "") {
    document.getElementById("refi_purp").className -= " no-display";
  } else if (whichone == "Test 2") {
    document.getElementById("refi_purp").className += " no-display";
  }
}
```

```css
.no-display {
  display: none;
 }
```

```html
<table width="100%" bordercolor="#000033">
  <tr>
    <td style="padding-left:30px">Drop Down 1</td>
    <td style="width:180px"><label name="h_sLoanPurp_err" include="yes"></label>
      <select id="h_sLoanPurp" NAME="h_sLoanPurp" onchange="RefiPurpose(this.value)" include="yes">
        <option value="">Please Choose One</option>
        <option value="Test 1">Test 1</option>
        <option value="Test 2">Test 2</option>
      </select>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="refi_purp">
    <td style="padding-left:30px" id="refi_purp_td">Drop Down 2:</td>
    <td><label name="h_refipurp_err" include="yes"></label>
      <select id="h_refipurp" NAME="h_refipurp" tabindex="60" include="yes" style="width: 170px"></select>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

But if you really want to keep the inline styling you can also replace the code inside the first `if` in your sample code with. `document.getElementById("refi_purp").style.display = "table-row";` and give the first option the `value=""` and it should work.

Comment: You're welcome. Also if this answers your question could you accept the answer, so the question is closed? :)